# Jquery add and remove active class in mutlilevel submenu

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery, so I'm sorry if this is a silly question. But I've been looking through Stack Overflow and I can find things that half work, I just can't get it to fully work.
I have a tab with 2 nested submenu, Once the main tab`(Products)` clicked, its get active again if I clicked submenu of `(products)` i.e.  `(Buttons)` , still main tab`(products)` is active , again if i clicked the Submenu of Buttons`(i.e. Button1)` , still Main tab`(Products)` and Submenu`(Buttons)` is active.

I want when I click the `submenu` of any tab the parent tab of that `Submenu` get Inactive.

Any help would be great!

Here's what I've tried.

**HTML File**

```
<ul>
    <li> <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="waves-effect"><i class="mdi mdi-home"></i><span> Home  </span></a> </li>
    <li class="has_sub"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="waves-effect"><i class="mdi mdi-album"></i> <span> Products </span> <span class="pull-right"><i class="mdi mdi-plus"></i></span></a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li class="has_sub"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="waves-effect"><span> Buttons </span> <span class="pull-right"><i class="mdi mdi-plus"></i></span></a>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><a href="#">Buttons1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Buttons2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Panels</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tabs &amp; Accordions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Modals</a></li>

</ul>
```

**Jquery**

```
 i.$leftMenuToggle.on("click", function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation(), i.openLeftBar()
        }), 
        i.$menuItem.on("click", i.menuItemClick), 
        i.$firstMenuChild.parents("li:last").children("a:first").addClass("active").trigger("click"), 

        i.$menuItem.each(function() {
            this.href == window.location.href && (e(this).addClass("active"), 
                e(this).parent().addClass("active"), 
                e(this).parent().parent().prev().addClass("active"), 
                e(this).parent().parent().prev().trigger("click"))
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below snippet for reference.

```js
$('a').click(function(){
  $('.myUL').find('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.active{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="myUL">
  <li> <a href="#" class="waves-effect"><i class="mdi mdi-home"></i><span> Home  </span></a> </li>
  <li class="has_sub"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="waves-effect"><i class="mdi mdi-album"></i> <span> Products </span> <span class="pull-right"><i class="mdi mdi-plus"></i></span></a>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li class="has_sub"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="waves-effect"><span> Buttons </span> <span class="pull-right"><i class="mdi mdi-plus"></i></span></a>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li><a href="#">Buttons1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Buttons2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Panels</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tabs &amp; Accordions</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Modals</a></li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: If possible can u plz make a solution in my given Jquery file.

Comment: for that you are suppose to share run-able code in snippet or fiddler. or at least your entire code. In your above code how do i come to know what is i?

Comment: Please Check-

`Html -` https://gist.github.com/anonymous/acb1896e58570cf01e2ba5fbe43294e0

`Jquery -` https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e3eef19514bd0a1429c7cef04f8662e7

Comment: It has only html!!

Comment: Now Check, by mistake i press enter after put the html link :)

Comment: not able to make it run-able one. please share your code in a fiddler

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157040/discussion-between-rajesh-rijo-and-prashant).